# How to run a loop until equation becomes true?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I have 3 variables a,b and c. They are random numbers from one to ten lets say. I want to run a loop until the random numbers fulfil the equation a+b+c=30 so I can exit the loop and run more code.
Any help would be great thanks, I'm just starting to learn JAVA and this is just a little project I gave myself.

```
import java.util.Random;

class ClassA{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random randomVariable = new Random();
        int a,b,c;

        a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
        b = randomVariable.nextInt(10);

        c=a+b;

        if(c==10){
            System.out.println
            ("I want to run c=a+b until it becomes true so I can run this.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [The `for` Statement.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html)

Comment: Please see the [Java tutorial for the `while` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html).

Comment: @user3561751 I've added an example with comments in my answer (using the while loop construct). Please let me know if you need any additional information. Good luck with Java!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple different constructs that you could use in order to satisfy these constraints, but the `while` loop might be the easiest to understand of them. Here's example code to help get you started:

```
import java.util.Random;

class ClassA {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Random randomVariable = new Random();
        int a,b,c;

        //initially generate your random variables
        a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
        b = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
        c = a + b;

        //check if the condition is met
        while(a + b + c != 30) {
           //if not, regenerate the numbers
           a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
           b = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
           c = a + b;
        }

        if(c==10) {
            System.out.println("Whatever you want");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The while loop runs the code within the block until the condition is satisfied.

```
while (a+b+c != 30) {
    // Regenerate numbers.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into while loops.

```
while(a+b+c!=30) {
    //Your code goes here     
    a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
    b = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using while() { } is an option but in this case do/while makes more sense because you always want to start with at least one attempt at random numbers.

```
do {
   a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
   b = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
   c = a + b;
} while(a + b + c != 30);
```

or

```
} while(a + b != 15);  // since c = a + b
```

Of course the loop itself is redundant as you can determine what is required without a loop.

```
a = randomVariable.nextInt(10);
b = 15 - a;
// a + b == 15 so a + b + c == 30;
```

If you want to ensure `a` and `b` are between 0 and 9, neither can be less than 6 (15 - 9) so

```
a = randomVariable.nextInt(4) + 6;
b = 15 - a;
// a + b == 15;
```

Since `c` must be 15, it can't be 10.